# Pandas: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a new column named **lead_actor_actress_known** whose values is boolean based on whether there value in 2nd column **lead_actor_actress** has value or not. If there is a value(Name of actors) populate 1st column using **True** if there is no value, return **False**

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'

My code is throwing an error above.

```
df['lead_actor_actress_known'] = df['lead_actor_actress'].apply(lambda x: True if x.isnull() else False)
```

What i'm i missing?

Comment: The series `df['lead_actor_actress']` is presumably a string like "Meryl Streep" which is why it has no isnull() attribute. Try `df['lead_actor_actress'].isnull()` to apply to the whole series.

Comment: The takeaway from @HenryEcker's comment, is to try not to use `.apply()`, and instead to use native pandas functions. You will save yourself a lot of pain down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use numpy's where:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df['lead_actor_actress_known'] = np.where(pd.isna(df['lead_actor_actress']), False, True)
```

I have put 'False' at first because you want a boolean = False when there's no value.

Answer (score 0):

When x is data frame, x.isnull() can be used. But u worked with str so you can use pd.isnull(x)

Can u try this code:

```
df['lead_actor_actress_known'] = df['lead_actor_actress'].apply(lambda x: 1 if pd.isnull(x) == True else 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Henry Ecker's comment contains the answer to this question, I am reproducing in the answer section for convenience. Replace your application of the `.apply()` method with the code `df['lead_actor_actress_known'] = df['lead_actor_actress'].isna()`.

The thing to know here is that `df['lead_actor_actress'].isna()` returns a "Boolean mask" (a series of True and False values) and this is exactly what you are asking to assign the variable `lead_actor_actress`.