# Python access pandas cell value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, apply

I have a sample csv file like below:

| latitude | longitude | street |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40.52689 | -74.16728 | Barclay Ave |
| 40.84077 | -73.87246 | Bronx River Parkway |
|  |  | Major Deegan |
| 40.69403 | -73.72679 | Cross Island Parkway |
| 40.85736 | -73.84657 |  |

I want to fill out the missing street name if the latitude and longitude are available, by calling geolocator.reverse(). Code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

df = pd.read_csv("C:sample.csv")

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myapp")

for a,b,c in zip(df.latitude, df.longitude, df.street):
    if c.isnull().values==True and a.isnull().values==False and b.isnull().values==False:
        coordinate=str(df["latitude"])+str(df["longitude"])
        location = geolocator.reverse(coordinate)
        df[c]=location.address
```

But I got "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'". Upon search, I find solution from [Pandas: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67660209/pandas-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-isnull), which is applying isnull to the whole series. But I don't want to do that since some of the street is already fill out, I don't want to overwrite it.

I also try np.where

```
np.where(df["street"].isnull() &
                        df["latitude"].notnull() &
                        df["longitude"].notnull(), 
                        coordinate=str(df["latitude"]) + str(df["longitude"])
                        location = geolocator.reverse(coordinate)
                        df["street"] = location.address,
                        df["street"])
```

Which throw me Invalid syntax.
Also try apply

```
df["street"].apply(lambda x: if (x.street.isnull() & (x.latitude.notnull() & x.longitude.notnull()))
                                coordinate=str(x.latitude)+str(x.longitude)
                                location = geolocator.reverse(coordinate)
                                x.street=location.address
                                else x.street)
```

Which also give me syntax error. Can't figure out why.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow this code correctly, but seems to me you could replace ```a.isnull()``` with ```a = ```, and ```b.isnull()```  with ```b == ''```.

Comment: It goes through, but the street for row 5 is still NaN

Comment: So what does geolocator return for the lat lon parameters?

Comment: It seems like the function is never been call.

Comment: So what is the value of coordinate when you call geolocator.reverse(coordinate)```

Comment: The coordinate is in row 5: 40.85736 -73.84657.

Comment: are you sure that is what the previous command is producing?  If it is, what happens when you hard code those coordinates into geolocator.reverse

Comment: Sorry, 
coordinate = "40.85736,73.84657"
location = geolocator.reverse(coordinate)
address = location.raw["address"]
city = address.get("city","")
state = address.get('state', '')
country = address.get('country', '')
print(city)
print(state)
print(country)

Comment: What do you get when you ```print(geolocator.reverse("40.85736,73.84657" )```?

Comment: also what do you get when you run ```print(geolocator.reverse("40.8573673.84657" )```

Comment: print(geolocator.reverse("40.85736,73.84657" ))
Ошская область, Кыргызстан.

print(geolocator.reverse("40.8573673.84657" )
ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point

Comment: Is the result of print(geolocator.reverse("40.85736,73.84657" )) Ошская область, Кыргызстан. what you expect?

Comment: Yes, I could change the language latter.

Comment: So does that produce a street address?

Comment: No... It only gave me state and country...

Comment: That is why you are getting NaN for street address

Comment: It should returned Ошская область, Кыргызстан, which at least the state and country. But the point is, the function is never been called if I change to =="" as you suggested.